# PHP help get_template_directory + PHP include

Tags: php, include

Sorry my PHP skills are lacking.

I want to use a php include in WP but I'd like to get the file path with `<?php get_template_directory(); ?>`

I can't figure out how that would look.

My non WP file looks like this:

```
<?php include 'inc/social.php'; ?>
```

Basically I don't know how to string two PHP commands together `get_template_directory` + include.

Comment: For a parent theme or child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) and [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) both pull form the `wp-content/themes` directory. The difference being that the former always pulls from the *parent* theme directory.

Neither take parameters, so you just concatenate the rest of the path to the string returned from the appropriate function. That is:

```
include get_template_directory().'/inc/social.php';
```

If your file is not in your theme directory, you cannot use those functions. They are very specifically theme functions.

Comment: This is correct. It should be noted that WordPress has a helper function `get_template_part()` for including sub-templates.

Comment: I thought about `get_template_part` but this strikes me as the kind of file that should not be easily replaceable.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. I am now interested in get_template_part. I'll look into that.